# 3 values (numbers) in 1 input separation. Python 3

Tags: python, input, python-3.x, code-separation

I'm working on a code right now that a part of it requires to ask the user for 3 different numbers in one line ( could be any number of digits in each number).
Say I ask the user for the input and he enters : "31 722 9191".
A space is required between the numbers. How would you go about separating these numbers and assigning a variable to each one of them. So for example 31 would be "A", 722 would be "B" and so on...
What I've got so far:

```
user_input = input(" Please enter the numbers: ")
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a combination of split and sequence unpacking.

```
user_input = user_input(" Please enter the numbers: ")
a, b, c = user_input.split()
```

`split` will take your string of numbers, say "x y z", and turn it into a list of elements in the string where the elements are all the words in the string that are separated by spaces. Thus `split` will yield the string ['x', 'y', 'z'] for input 'x y z'.

Since a list is a form of sequence, its elements can be "unpacked" and assigned to a list of variables of your choosing.

Comment: Further clarity for OP: .split() is taking the string and turning it into a list. It  breaks up the string around whitespace by default, but you can pass it other things like `user_input.split(",")` would be the solution here if you wanted the user to yield the digits by entering "31,722,9191"

Comment: I dunno which version of python is this,but now you can only write ```a,b,c=input("enter 3 ints")```

Answer (score 3):

```
x = (input("Enter 3 user inputs: ").split())

a = int(x[0])
b = int(x[1])
c = int(x[2])

print(f"A: {a}, B: {b}, C: {c}")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do like this

```
a, b, c = [int(x) for x in input("Please enter the numbers: ").split()]
```